# Fetch the latitude and longitude after regular intervals in php and use the updated latitude and longitude values to update the marker position

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have fetched the latitude and longitudes for all the gps devices in php. What i want is that in php , this latitude and longitude gets updated every 30 seconds. After the values are updated, i want to update the marker  positions based on these values. I have scratched my head a lot for this but everytime i enter into ajax,javascript and php together, the things confuse me. My code is :-

```
$returned_content=get_data($value->URL."&sDate=".$sdate."&eDate=".$edate);
//url gives the latitude and longitude

$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($returned_content);
$json=$xmlObj->GetGPSData;
error_log($json);
$json_decode=json_decode($json);

foreach($json_decode as $row){
    $lat_d= $row->Latitude;
    echo("\n");
    $long_d= $row->Longitude;
}
<html>
    <head>
<?php
     //   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="40" />
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api
    /js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        xar latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat_d; ?>, <?php echo $long_d; ?>);

        var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 16,
                    center: latlng,
                    panControl: true,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    scaleControl: true,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }


        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
<?php
    echo "addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(".$lat_d.", ".$long_d."), map);";
?>

    }


    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        "http://4vector.com/i/free-vector-yellow-bus-clip-art_109340_Yellow_Bus_clip_art_hight.png",
        null, //size is determined at RUNTIME
        null, // origin is 0,0
        null, // anchor is bottom center of the scaled image

        new google.maps.Size(62,22)
    );

    function addMarker(latLng, map) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: icon,
                    draggable: true, // enables drag & drop
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
        return marker;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
        <body onload="initialize()">
            <div style="float:left; position:relative; width:550px; border:0px #000 solid;">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="width:1421px;height:700px;border:solid black 1px;"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I will be so very thankful to the person who can help me with this. because its going above my head now

Comment: If you want to update the map every 30 seconds you need to do all the position gathering in javascript, or write an AJAX interface to a php script that you can run every 30 seconds to collect positions and provide the positions as data (JSON) to the javascript so you can replot the markers

Comment: Sir all my code is in one single page so how should i write the ajax code that will bring the php values for me  every 30 seconds

Comment: Research, research, research

Comment: Everytime i do this sir, the entire page gets loaded but i want to load the values of latitude and longitude and then update only map markers. I have done eough search but i am not able to understand on how actually i will update the markers with this flow

Comment: Then you should consider paying someone that can understand the process. Its not a trivial piece of coding you are trying to get someone to do for you. SO **is not a free coding resource**

Comment: Thanks for the idea that you gave me above ie using ajax,php and json. I think  i am trying to move forward with that. I dont need the code sir. Please dont take me wrong. Its just that some things are clear to u being an experienced person and those things are not for any other person because he is a new person in this field. Thanks for your help. T

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use php code in javascript the same way as you'd use it in html.

Instead, try using a (JQuery) AJAX call to access an external php script, and fetch the results from there.

Example:

```
var myLongLat = 0;
$.post('getLongLat.php', { id: 1}, function(result) { 
   myLongLat = result;
});
```